# Sql merge columns with same name

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table of hockey games and a table of teams.

schedule:
[image]

teams:
[image]

I am trying to do 2 joins on the same column.  I have a schedule of home and away teams in table 'schedule'.  I am trying to look up the names of the teams in 2022.  Simple query below

```
SELECT `schedule`.`date`, `2022`.`Team` AS AWAY FROM `schedule`
JOIN `2022`ON `2022`.`NUM` = `schedule`.`away`
WHERE `schedule`.`date` = '2022-10-21' AND `schedule`.`league` = 1
```

Results

```
 [date] => 2022-10-21
 [AWAY] => Tampa Bay Lightning
```

What I am trying to get is:

[image]

I am trying to also look up the home row in the same query.

```
SELECT `schedule`.`date`, `2022`.`Team` as AWAY FROM `schedule`
(JOIN `2022`ON `2022`.`NUM` = `schedule`.`away`) AND (JOIN `2022`ON `2022`.`NUM` =     `schedule`.`home`)
WHERE `schedule`.`date` = '2022-10-21' AND `schedule`.`league` = 1
```

This does not work, can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: Perhaps you could check out the query syntax definition in the manual to see how to join three tables. If you're joining the same table twice, you'll need to assign different aliases (correlation names) to them to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
SELECT EE.date, AW.TEAM, HO.TEAM
FROM schedule AS EE
JOIN `2022` AW ON `AW`.`NUM` = `EE`.`away`
JOIN `2022` HO ON `HO`.`NUM` = `EE`.`home`
WHERE `EE`.`date` = '2022-10-21' AND `EE`.`league` = 1
```